# Export DAE animation from 3ds max to Xcode with correct bounding box

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, scenekit, 3ds

I'm trying to convert some fbx animation to DAE file in 3ds max, and then use it in Xcode with SceneKit. It almost works, but there is a problem when I'm trying to get bounding box of this node in SceneKit. Bounding box seems to be much larger than node itself. It also shows when I try to add Physics body in Xcode. Probably I need to do something in 3ds before exporting, but I don't know what. Does anyone know how to prepare such animation, so that bounding box will be responding to node size?

Code for loading model is very simple:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "(model.name).dae")!; 
object.model3D = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "MDL_Obj", recursively: false)!
```

I think that bounding box itself is correct, but this animation is transformed, scaled or something (I'm not an expert in 3d). Bounding box is 90x131x22 - same as physics body in Xcode scene editor, and the person in animation itself is more than 2x smaller.

Here is this animation, maybe someone can help.

[dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40968624/Serah.dae](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40968624/Serah.dae)

Header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
<asset>
<contributor>
<authoring_tool>SceneKit Collada Exporter v1.0</authoring_tool>
</contributor>
<created>2016-12-21T06:43:57Z</created>
<modified>2016-12-21T06:43:57Z</modified>
<unit meter="0.025400"/>
<up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis>
</asset>
<library_animations>
<animation id="mixamorig_RightHandRing1-Matrix-animation-transform">
<source id="genericSource1">
...
```

Node itself:

[image: Node itself]

Bounding box:
[image: Bounding box]

Comment: Smells like it might be a units problem. What's the bounding box reported by SceneKit? What do you think it should be instead? Can we see the code that loads the model?

Comment: Code for loading model is very simple:
            let scene = SCNScene(named: "\(model.name).dae")!;
            object.model3D = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "MDL_Obj", recursively: false)!
I think that bounding box itself is correct, but this animation is transformed, scaled or something (I'm not an expert in 3d). Bounding box is 90x131x22 - same as physics body in Xcode scene editor, and the person in animation itself is more than 2x smaller. Here is this animation, maybe someone can help. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40968624/Serah.dae

Comment: I viewed your .DAE file with the bounding boxes: http://imgur.com/6tMhfid. As you can see in that image, one of the bounding box stretches way to the left. Can you check your DAE file without the animation and the rig, just the geometry. Then see if the bounding box is as per your expectations. Also reading the Bounding Volume docs, https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnboundingvolume, implies some geometry in your bounding box has a vertex in model space resulting in the bounding box you see.